# Flutter -The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm  trying to run my app on android emulator and i keep getting this error :

```
   `The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
    [!] Flutter tried to create the file `android/settings_aar.gradle`, but failed.
To manually update `settings.gradle`, follow these steps:
1. Copy `settings.gradle` as `settings_aar.gradle`
2. Remove the following code from `settings_aar.gradle`:
    def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()
    assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle  /app_plugin_loader.gradle"
Exception: Please create the file and run this command again.'
```

settings.gradle file :

```
include ':app'

 def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir,   "local.properties")
    def properties = new Properties()

   assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
   localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->     properties.load(reader) }

  def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
  assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in    local.properties"
  apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle   /app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your project properly for AndroidX ?
Instruction [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration)

if even after that you are still facing this issue, you have to change gradle version

```
android/build.gradle---
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

after making any change in your project you need to refresh project cached settings
run in terminal

```
 flutter clean 
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong related to your `android/settings.gradle` file. It should look like this:

```
include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

And your `android/app/build.gradle` file should look like this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example" 
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```